# Using Comparison test with complex numbers

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

So I want to show the convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^{2} i^{k}}{k^{4}+1}$ using the comparison test. So I want to bound the $\frac{k^{2} i^{k}}{k^{4}+1}$ with a known number. I tried $< \frac{k^2i^k}{k^4} = \frac{i^k}{k^2}$ But here is where I get stuck because $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{i^{k}}{k^{2}}$ converge only if $k$ is even since we get that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{k^{2}}$$? How did I move forward from this point?

Comment: There is no notion of 'less than' in the set of complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $\sum |a_k| <\infty$ implies that $\sum a_k$ is convergent.

Here, $|\frac {k^{2}i^{k}} {k^{4}+1}| \leq \frac 1  {k^{2}}$ and $\sum \frac  1 {k^{2}} <\infty$ so the given series is absolutely convergent.